# Lower a drain basket

Tags: sink

I need to lower this dish drain apparatus so I can slide it under the lip of a counter.

I thought about using my bench grinder but it was no workable.

[image]

Comment: It is plastic, so bench grinder would not work

Comment: Have you tried a box knife, scissors, a hack saw, or anything like that?  You don't need power tools for this if you don't have the right ones.

Comment: The problem is not in the cutting, but getting each leg even size after.  If not cutting right to the base, a piece of tape(masking) with a mark at the length will help.  I have an old(50 plus year) paring knife that would cut that.

Comment: @jay613 I do not need perfect leg heights. I have a hacksaw. Your idea is being carefully considered.

Comment: @jay613 You get the gold star. I used a hacksaw to shorten the legs. :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because modifying a hunk of plastic is stretching the concept of "Home Improvement" to the limit. This would be better off at [lifehacks.se], more likely.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an oscillating tool with a fine tooth blade.  I assume you just want to cut the legs down a little.

I'd probably make a cutting guide out of abs plumbing pipe that fits around the legs so I could get the legs cut uniformly.

Comment: `oscillating tool ` which one

Comment: @Fresh Codemonger I do not have an oscillating tool. Need another option. I have a saber saw and a fine blade?

Comment: Heck, you could do it with sandpaper, a knife, shears, wire cutters, or a rough rock if that's what you have on hand... Probably even a smooth rockif you rub long enough or are able to hammer it flat. I'm not sure what you're looking for in the way of answers here; we don't know what your resources are, we can't what the plastic is, all we can do is throw random things at you.

Comment: You can get one for $14 from harborfreight.  https://www.harborfreight.com/16-amp-single-speed-oscillating-multi-tool-62866.html

Comment: @Fresh Codemonger That looks like a neat tool and a good price.